# What's the "printing difference" between `git tag` and `git describe --tags`?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

`git tag` seems to print in a separate process (window? app?) whereas `git describe --tags` is printed "in place". I can achieve the same printing behavior with `git tag` as `git describe --tags` by doing `git tag | tee`.

`tee` will "*read from standard input and write to standard output and files*"(copied from `man tee`). Does that mean that `git tag` doesn't normally print to standard output?

Note that I'm only using git as an example command, the same "printing difference" I find between `man xyz` and `cat xyz.txt`

So, what is the difference between the two? Primarily; what type of "state" do I reach when i type `man` or `git tag`? How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `git tag` uses a pager (again by default, `less`). This can be [configured using `pager.tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_configuration):

> `pager.tag` is only respected when listing tags, i.e., when `-l` is used or implied. The default is to use a pager. See [git-config[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

`git tag` implies `-l`.

You can override this temporarily by setting `PAGER` for a single `git tag` invocation:

```
PAGER= git tag
```

or redirecting `git tag`’s output to `cat`:

```
git tag | cat
```

`git describe --tags` *doesn’t* use a pager.